# Use of leading $ in CSS3 property values

Tags: css

Recently I found the following CSS3 in an example

```
#sidebar {
........
}

#container {
left: $sidebar-width;
}
```

This appears to say -- use the value of the width property in the object identified as **sidebar** as the property value. Could anyone point me at authoritive documentation describing this syntax or otherwise explain what is intended by this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code provided is either [SASS (SCSS really)](http://sass-lang.com/) or pseudo-code to represent a variable value determined by the `width` of the `#sidebar`.